# Unable to update column values using CASE expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update some of the values of a table column using UPDATE statement. However, I am not able to get the updated labels 'inhibitor' and 'activator; inhibitor' in the final output.

```
update schema.table
set action_norm = (case 
                   when action in (     
                                         'inhibitor', 
                                          'DNA Inhibitor', 
                                          'RNA Inhibitor', 
                                          'RNA Synthesis Inhibitor', 
                                          'RNA Synthesis Inhibitor') then 'inhibitor'
                                  
                   when action ilike '%agonist; antagoniost%' then 'activator; inhibitor'
                   else action
                   end)
```

How can I modify my query to get the desired output?

```
action                    action_norm
inhibitor                 Inhibitor 
DNA Inhibitor             inhibitor 
RNA Inhibitor             inhibitor 
RNA Synthesis Inhibitor   inhibitor 
RNA Synthesis Inhibitor   inhibitor 
agonist; antagoniost      activator; inhibitor
```

The output I am getting is:

```
action                    action_norm
inhibitor                 inhibitor
DNA Inhibitor             DNA Inhibitor
RNA Inhibitor             RNA Synthesis Inhibitor
RNA Synthesis Inhibitor   RNA Synthesis Inhibitor
RNA Synthesis Inhibitor   RNA Synthesis Inhibitor
agonist; antagoniost      agonist; antagoniost
```

Comment: What is the actual output you get?

Comment: Just added in the OP

Answer (score 0):

@rshar Looks like you hava a typo, because query

```
select
case
 when action in (     
                   'inhibitor', 
                   'DNA Inhibitor', 
                   'RNA Inhibitor', 
                   'RNA Synthesis Inhibitor', 
                   'RNA Synthesis Inhibitor') then 'inhibitor'
 when action ilike '%agonist; antagoniost%' then 'activator; inhibitor'
 else action
 end
from (select 'agonist; antagoniost' as action) as t
```

returns exactly "activator; inhibitor" as you want.

Comment: Thanks !! However, the other condition still left unresolved. The one with 'inhibitor'